# PyCharm - can't use remote interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-debugging, interpreter, jetbrains-ide

Strange thing. I just can't use remote interpreters. I'm 100% sure I saw it before. WTF?

I have configured ssh deployment connection and vagrant box.

There is nothing interesting under `more` button.

How to add remote interpreter?

edit: screenshot from settings → project → project interpreter

edit2: [problem reported on PyCharm community support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206702819-Missing-Add-Remote-option-in-the-Project-Interpreter-configuration)

edit3: I use PyCharm pro

edit4: Just installed today's new version, 2016.1.3. Nothing has changed.

[image]

```
PyCharm 2016.1.2
Build #PY-145.844, built on April 8, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b32 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

[image]

Comment: Can you set a remote interpreter in `Settings > Project > Project Interpreter`?

Comment: @tschale - nope, screenshot from my question is from cog on this config page

Comment: Damn... I'm afraid I can't help you...

Comment: I remove the remote interpreter，and recreate it，then it works。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok, problem solved.

1. export settings (I already had my old settings)
2. remove settings dir (`~/.PyCharm2016.1`)
3. restart pycharm without importing settings
4. import settings
5. restart PyCharm
6. :tada: it works!

Answer (score 12):

Check that the Python Remote Interpreter plugin is activated.

Go to Settings -> Plugins. Check that Python Remote Interpreter is checked off.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem like this plugin exists anymore today?

Comment: could not find the plugin in pycharm community version 2021.3

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're using the community edition of PyCharm. I suppose that's what they refer to as "Remote development capabilities":
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/

Try to install the trial of the professional edition to verify this. You should be able to see an `Add Remote` option that allows you to specify the host vagrant instance dir and python interpreter path inside the virtual:

[image: pycharm vagrant dev]

Comment: I've been through this. Only professional version works with remote debugger :(

Comment: OP's screenshot suggests they're using the profession edition?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, the problem is with the plugin, but not the one that [AYTWebSolutions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2551194/aytwebsolutions) suggested.

Enable `FTP(S)/SFTP Connectivity (ex. Remote Hosts Access)`. This solves the problem.

CAUTION: First, I did what [voy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338790/voy) suggested and I lost my license. His solution just resets the plugins to the defaults but you can enable the needed plugin yourself and it works without having the risk of losing your license data.

Comment: Best answer, worked for PyCharm 2022.3.3 Professional. Restart PyCharm after activating the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by **unsetting** a simple option switch in the current version of PyCharm [PyCharm 2023.1 (Professional Edition) / Apple Silicon version]

Switch for that is '*Visible only for this project*' which basically allowed my to go forward, even tho I set up the config for/within the same project.
[image: Visible only for this project]