# Pycharm Professional doesn't have remote SSH interpreter option

Tags: pycharm

I have Pycharm Professional Edition 2021.2.3 with an activated license. I don't see the [SSH Interpreter option](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html) for project interpreter. Anyone know how I can get that option?

Someone asked a similar question [a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159539/pycharm-cant-use-remote-interpreter). But it's been a while with Pycharm changes. I figured I'd ask again.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered by Sergey [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000218540-SSH-Interpreter?page=1#community_comment_4408785807506).

> check Preferences | Plugins and make sure you don't have the bundled plugins disabled, especially FTP/SFTP Connectivity one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Existing Environment option and then hit the 3 dots.

The select the SSH interpreter.

Ther you can add a new one or select an existing one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer, but I don't even have the "SSH interpreter" option on my left hand side. See my screenshot above.